# Not working kurento-one2one-call-advanced

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I download this tutorial https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/tree/master/kurento-one2one-call-advanced. try to run with two systems. ONE: register as alice and TWO: register as bob. When alice call t bob getting flowing error.

log in kurento:

```
 Senging message: {"id":"register","name":"pratik"}
    Received message: {"id":"registerResponse","response":"accepted"}
    chrome: {"audio":true,"video":{"optional":[{"minWidth":640},{"maxWidth":640},{"minFramerate":15},{"maxFramerate":15}]}}
    {}
```

Error in console:

```
NavigatorUserMediaError {}
constraintName: ""
message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)."
name: "PermissionDeniedError"
__proto__: NavigatorUserMediaError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't run this example on two different system. Run this example with two different tab on same system. It will work. `message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)."` this is cross domain error, go through link.